# Is there any benefit to using self-signed certificates for code signing over not signing C# binaries at all?

Tags: c#, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I'm a hobbyist programmer who maintains some programs written in C# (game mods in particular). I distribute those by uploading the DLL in a zip file to a website. Whenever I upload a new version, users would get a "suspicious download" warning. From what I heard, this warning goes away after a lot of people have downloaded it, but this has to happen for every new release.

I know that code signing can help in this area and I see three options:

1. Buy a certificate at ~250$/year;
2. Use a self-signed certificate;
3. Don't change anything and keep shipping unsigned binaries.

While I can afford option 1, I feel this is still too steep a price for what's just a hobby. Plus I'm fine with sticking to option 3. However I've been looking into option 2 and wondering if it provides any benefits compared to option 3.

1. Do browsers/operating systems indeed have some reputation system that causes the "suspicious download" for unsigned binaries to disappear after a while?
2. Would using a self-signed certificate allow that reputation to carry over to new builds?
3. Are there any other benefits/downsides to using self signed certificates for code signing, compared to not signing the binary at all?
4. Is there perhaps a fourth option that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Self signed wont do anything for your end-users. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate - "These self-signed certificates are easy to make and do not cost money. However, they do not provide any trust value" #1 is the best way of protecting not only your reputation, but also your users.

Comment: That isn't true. A self-signed certificate does provide the (minimal) trust that two different binaries were signed by the same author. Hence my question. Of course some caveats apply as there's no revocation system.

Comment: @bcmpinc except the problem is that someone else could do the same thing, claiming to be you, but distributing malware instead. That's the whole point of having a limited number of trusted roots. Now if your users REALLY liked you I suppose you could make a self-signed root and ask them to install it in their trusted root stores. Then you sign your binaries with that. That would bypass all of this. But who realistically would do that? I wouldn't (even if your stuff was awesome, which I'm sure it is!)

Comment: I wouldn't dare asking my users to compromise their system's security by installing a self-signed root certificate.

I don't really see the difference between me using a self-signed certificate to claim being a random person on the internet or someone doing the same. The trust does not come from who I claim to be, but from what I do: creating & maintaining mods for several years. That's too much effort for people with ill intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All great questions. By way of quick background for other readers, both the browser and the operating system might flag any EXE, DLL, MSI, etc. downloaded, with or without a trusted signature. They all have different algorithms for how they decide to flag, the precise detials of which are not widely publicized (if at all). However the common factors I know of are:

1. How many times the *file* has been downloaded (irrespective of signature).
2. How many times have files *signed by that same certificate* been downloaded.
3. Assuming a signature, is the certificate Extended Validation (EV) or regular.

> Do browsers/operating systems indeed have some reputation system that causes the "suspicious download" for unsigned binaries to disappear after a while?

Yes they do, but in my anecdotal experience it requires a LOT more reputation than you're likely to accumulate unless your application is extremely popular. For example the installer for [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) has no digital signature and I've never seen Chrome or Windows flag it. But that's 7Zip.

> Would using a self-signed certificate allow that reputation to carry
> over to new builds?

Again based on my experience, this is true for trusted certificates, although this benefit resets with each renewal. I'm afraid I can't answer with certainty if this would work for untrusted self-signed certs. (If you asked me to wager, though, I would say not, for reasons below).

> Are there any other benefits/downsides to using self signed certificates for code signing, compared to not signing the binary at all?

I am speculating, but there is good reason for an algorithm to be more suspicious of an untrusted self-signature than no signature at all, interpreting it as a possible attempt to spoof a reputable author. Otherwise you could self-sign a certificate as "Microsoft Corporation", for example, and enough users might be fooled by that into ignoring and clicking past the warning for the algorithm to eventually start passing it. While there are legitimate cases for self-signing (corporate environments with a single trusted root, development machines, etc.), the root would be in the trusted root store in those cases. For distribution to the general public, it could easily be viewed as sketchy.

> Is there perhaps a fourth option that I'm not aware of?

There is, but it's probably not an option for you specifically as a hobbyist - extended validation (EV) certificates give you the highest level of trust possible right out of the gate, potentially even with no prior download history.

They are much more expensive than a regular cert, and they're only available if you're a legally incorporated entity. Even then there are numerous hoops to go through. But as a distributor of fairly esoteric B2B software with frequnt updates and professional customers with little patience for technical difficulties, we had no choice but to get one or deal with constant recurring issues, both browser and OS. Ever since, we have never to my knowledge had a download blocked by the browser or the OS (Z-Scalar and systems like that are a different matter, but you usually have no option there except to beg your customer to beg their IT department to whitelist you).

Comment: Some builds have been downloaded over 100.000 times, so I suspect the reputation system did kick in there. Would be nice if I could communicate that the new build was also made by me (without the 250$/y price tag).

Comment: Wow, 100k downloads and you're not making money off it? You must be very dedicated!  Not sure what site you're looking at but there are some who advertise code signing certs (not EV) for much less per year. https://www.ssl.com/certificates/code-signing/ for example. Can't vouch for them but definitely shop around. I doubt there's much difference in terms of trust level between different non-EV cert providers.